# AS3 Array reordering on insert

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, recursion

I have an application that allow user to define the order of elements by simply defining an index on each element (the elements are xml files loaded at the runtime).

The rule is simple, higher is the index, higher is the element in the layer stack (just like z-index in CSS).
But if there is 2 elements at the same index, I have to add the last element right after the existing one. And, if the new computed index is taken, I have to move the content of the list to make a place to put the new item. And this, recursively.

Here is the sample of what the structure look like:

```
+---+--------------+
| 1 | lowest item  |
+---+--------------+
| 2 | lower item   |
+---+--------------+ <== if I add an element at the index 3, there is no problem
| 4 | higher item  |
+---+--------------+
| 9 | highest item |
+---+--------------+
```

But, if the index 3 is already taken, i have to insert the new item just after, at index 4. And if the 4 is already taken too, i have to move the existing 4 to the index 5 to place the new item, and this, recursively....

```
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
| 1 | item 1        |            | 1 | item 1            |
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
| 2 | item 2        |            | 2 | item 2            |
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
| 3 | already taken |     ==>    | 3 | already taken     |
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
| 4 | item 4        |            | 4 | << NEW ITEM 3 >>  |
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
| 9 | item 5        |            | 5 | previously item 4 |
+---+---------------+            +---+-------------------+
                                 | 9 | item 5            |
                                 +---+-------------------+
```

The number of element can vary, and the list don't alway begin a index 1.
For example, the list can contain the indexes: `1, 2, 3, 5, 10` as well as `30, 32, 52, 9999`.

I have tried so much ways that my brain hurt. I am lost in all these recursive function, which even don't work.
If anybody know a working way to perform this reordering, it would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, I think I will jump of a bridge.
I was able to solve my problem with 2 functions of 4 rows. Shame on me.

Here is the result.

```
    public function add(index:int, item:Object):void
    {
        if(index in _list){
            index++;
            move(index);
        }
        _list[index] = item;
    }
    private function move(index:int):void
    {
        if(index+1 in _list){
            move(index+1);
        }
        _list[index+1] = _list[index];
        delete _list[index];
    }
```

If you see an even more easier way to do it, don't hesitate to say it.

Answer (score 0):

So you're creating an array-like structure.

Why don't you use a (double) linked list instead? So each element will have a reference/link to the next one (the last one will have null).

If you want to insert an element you need to update only two items with new links...

Or, if you're using Array use [`splice`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29) method to insert new item.